# Suguru puzzles with no given clues

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

A Suguru puzzle consists of a bunch of polynominoes fit together in a rectangular shape. The goal of the puzzle is to fill all the cells in all the polynominoes with the numbers $1$ to the amount of cells the polynomino has. A pentomino requires you to fill in $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$, for example. A number is not allowed to touch the same number, not diagonally either!

Recently I was wondering if it is possible to construct a Suguru puzzle without any given clues (no given numbers) with exactly one solution. I was able to find some examples so I started wondering for which sizes this would work. So my question is:

> For which $a$, $b$ is it possible to construct an $a\times b$ Suguru puzzle with no given clues and exactly one solution?

I was able to prove some cases, but not all cases.

- I was able to prove that if $a$ and $b$ are both odd, than there exists a possible arrangement with no given clues and exactly one solution unless both $a$ and $b$ are equal to $3$, in which case it is impossible to construct one.
- If one side is even and the other one is odd, I was able to proof that there exists an arrangement if the even side is at least $6$ and the odd side at least $3$. If the odd side is equal to $1$ than no arrangement with the other side being even exists.
- If the even side is equal to either $2$ or $4$, I am not sure whether it will ever be possible to construct a puzzle with no given clues and exactly one solution. So far I have not been able to find any working examples, so I believe there aren't any at all.
- With the help of the $8 \times 8$ configuration which was provided by Richard Tobin, I was also able to prove that an arrangement exists if $a$ and $b$ are both even and at least 8, however, I still haven't figured out what happens if $a$ and $b$ are both even, but not both at least 8.
- With the help of the $6 \times 6$ configuration provided by Kris van Bael I was able to prove all $even \times even$ are possible if both evens are at least 6, slightly improving the argument from before.
- With the help of Kris van Bael who also provided a working 5x4 I was able to prove all $4 \times odd$ work if the odd is at least 5. It is not hard to prove that $3 \times 4$ is impossible.

This brings all the unsolved cases down to two categories.
$2\times n$ for all $n$ and $4\times n$ for all even $n$

Does anyone know how I could prove all cases, or just some of the cases I have not yet already solved?

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A clueless 2-row Suguru must contain a region of size at least 5, as shown in my answer to the [related question on Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119003/empty-suguru-tectonic-puzzle/119017), and cannot have any region spanning both rows. Even with those difficulties, it's difficult to prove anything concrete.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an 8x8 suguru with no clues and one solution (so your conjecture that there are none with both sides even is wrong):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|           |           |       |
|---+---+---+---+---+   +---+---|
|               |   |       |   |
|---+---+   +---+   +---+---+   |
|   |   |   |       |       |   |
|   +   +---+   +   +   +---+   |
|   |       |       |   |       |
|---+   +   +---+---+   +   +---|
|   |       |   |       |   |   |
|   +---+---+   +---+---+---+   |
|   |           |   |           |
|   +---+   +---+   +---+---+   |
|   |   |   |       |       |   |
|---+---+---+---+   +---+   +---|
|               |       |       |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Can I ask how you were able to find this one?

Comment: Using your 8x8 configuration I was able to prove that if a and b are both even and at least 8, it is also always possible to make a suguru with no given clues. So thank you for this!

Comment: I wrote a program to generate puzzles and see if they were uniquely solvable.  I have not been able to find a 6x6 - if there is one, it must contain a polyomino of size 6.

Comment: I wrote similar program. Biggest empty puzzles so far found are 9x9. Will take challenge to search 6x6.

Answer (score 3):

I have a bit an obsession for empty Suguru puzzles. So happy to have found this old question and learn that I'm not alone.

Similar to Richard Tobin, I also wrote a program to search for such puzzles (and have a lot of fun to solve manually). But he did it almost 2 years earlier.

So, here are some more interesting sizes:

**5x3**
The smallest size for non-trivial puzzles:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+   
|       |           |   
+---+---+---+---+---+   
|               |   |   
+---+   +---+---+   +   
|   |   |           |   
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**5x4**
Disproving Rubenscube's 3rd bullet.

```
+---+---+---+---+   
|   |       |   |   
+---+---+---+   +   
|       |       |   
+   +---+   +---+   
|   |   |   |   |   
+   +   +   +   +   
|   |   |   |   |   
+---+   +---+   +   
|           |   |   
+---+---+---+---+
```

**6x6**
As to your 4th bullet.

Rare, but they exist. Here's a 1 in 10 million find:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+   
|   |           |       |   
+   +---+---+   +---+---+   
|           |       |   |   
+---+---+---+---+---+   +   
|   |           |       |   
+   +---+   +---+---+   +   
|   |   |   |       |   |   
+   +   +   +---+   +   +   
|   |   |       |   |   |   
+---+   +---+---+   +---+   
|           |   |       |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**9x9**
The biggest size I found so far.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   
|               |               |   |   
+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+   +   
|               |   |   |   |       |   
+---+   +---+---+   +---+   +   +---+   
|   |   |           |       |   |   |   
+   +---+---+---+   +---+   +   +   +   
|       |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
+---+---+   +   +---+   +---+---+   +   
|           |   |           |       |   
+---+   +---+   +   +---+---+---+   +   
|   |   |   |   |   |       |   |   |   
+   +---+   +   +---+---+---+   +---+   
|   |       |       |   |       |   |   
+   +---+   +---+---+   +   +   +---+   
|       |       |       |       |   |   
+   +---+---+---+---+   +---+---+   +   
|   |               |       |       |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

See also:
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119003/empty-suguru-tectonic-puzzle/119969#119969

and

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119245/happy-2023-another-empty-suguru-tectonic?rq=1

Comment: Congratulations on finding the 6x6.  Is it possible to find a 6x6 with one each of blocks size 1-8?  That would be rather elegant.

Comment: Yo, this is awesome. I can check off some more cases now! We are getting very close to finding them all!

Comment: Also if you are looking for big sizes, I can make them in any very large size you want. For a lot of these you can inductively add 2x2 blocks on the sides (and for odd sides an additional 1x2) to extend them, that is also how I do the extension proofs. If all cases are found I might write a short paper on the findings

Comment: @RichardTobin sizes running up to 8: I highly doubt it exist. I gave up after testing 10M arrangements. Most had multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We can rule out a number of cases by considering how many blocks are allowed and required.

An mxn puzzle cannot have more than ⌈m/2⌉⌈n/2⌉ blocks, otherwise there would be two adjacent ones.  (⌈x⌉ is the ceiling or "round up" operator.)  This is an example of the rather trivial "N kings" problem.

A clueless puzzle with k blocks will need one of each block size 1..k, using k(k+1)/2 squares, so this must be less than or equal to mn for those blocks to fit.  And it will need at least a further ⌈(m*n - k(k-1)/2) / k⌉ blocks for the remaining squares.

Combining these, k + ⌈(m*n - k(k-1)/2) / k⌉ must be less than or equal to ⌈m/2⌉⌈n/2⌉.

For example, a 6x6 puzzle with a maximum block size of 5 requires at least 5+5=10 blocks, but cannot have more than 9, so this is impossible.

Applying this to 2xn, we find there is no possible maximum block size for n < 13.

For 4xn, 4x5 is not excluded (and can be done, as Kris's example shows), but 4x6 is impossible.  4x8 might be possible with a maximum block size of 6 or 7.